# Netbeans 7.4 : Trying to delete project produces error

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am trying to delete a project in a swing based application, using " DefaultProjectOperations.performDefaultDeleteOperation"

But i keep getting this error.

The only stacktrace i have is the following one, but right now i am clueless as what could i be doing wrong, or even if this could be a netbeans defect.

I am using Netbeans 7.4 IDE. I cannot upgrade to v.8.0 as using this IDE it is a client specification.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempt to delete project that does not support deletion.
at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.support.DefaultProjectOperations.performDefaultDeleteOperation(DefaultProjectOperations.java:85)
at com.elitel5000.plugin.project.ElitelProject$ProyectoActionProvider.invokeAction(ElitelProject.java:219)
at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.ProjectAction$2.run(ProjectAction.java:186)
at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEvent(Mutex.java:1348)
at org.openide.util.Mutex.writeAccess(Mutex.java:462)
at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.ProjectAction.runSequentially(ProjectAction.java:183)
at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.ProjectAction$1$1.run(ProjectAction.java:139)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)

[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [DefaultProjectOperations documentation](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-projectuiapi/org/netbeans/spi/project/ui/support/DefaultProjectOperations.html#performDefaultDeleteOperation%28org.netbeans.api.project.Project%29), the exception is thrown because `ProjectOperations.isDeleteOperationSupported` returns false. According to the [documentation for that method](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-projectapi/org/netbeans/spi/project/support/ProjectOperations.html?is-external=true#isDeleteOperationSupported%28org.netbeans.api.project.Project%29), false is returned because the project does not implement the interface [DeleteOperationImplementation](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-projectapi/org/netbeans/spi/project/DeleteOperationImplementation.html).
As far as I can tell, you need to implement that interface to delete the project.

Comment: Hello McLovin, I will put your answer as the accepted one. I will see where the rabbit hole goes and write another question in these forums if i happen to hit another wall. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope that this works, as I wasn't able to test it.